# The Validation not working , the error message wont show up Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Im a laravel beginner, also my first time to use a framework i just learned laravel for 5 days,so i don't understand much about this framework, im using the latest laravel 8 i have a problem with my project, when trying to validate the data from the form.

1. i dont know this method is working or not (Probably not)

   ```
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'icons' => 'required',
    ]);
   ```
2. when i trying to get the error message {{$error}} , only showing [] in my view.

> 

```
<form action="{{ route('poseicon.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
     <div class="display">
     
        <label>name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <label>icons:</label>
        <input type="file" name="icons" id="icons" class="">
        {{$errors}}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

this is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'icons' => 'required',
    ]);
    //this working correctly when validate method above deleted 
    $file = $request->file('icons');
    $filename = 'pose-photo-' . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $path = $file->storeAs('img', $filename);

    //this also working correctly when validate method above deleted 
    Poseicon::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'icons' =>  $filename
    ]);
    
    return redirect('/poseicon');
    
}
```

i already try all the documentation said but still not working

Comment: you should only get the errors when submit the form with empty fields, at least that's what your rules are saying

Comment: yeah i try to submit the form without inputing anything, but still didnt show anything

Comment: Put a `@dd(session()->all())` in your blade and then submit empty form. Check if it has errors key in it.

Comment: ok , let me try

Comment: there is only showing up csrf token key in array

Comment: @shinichirouikebe Have you this line `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,` in your http/Kernel.php ? in `web` middlewareGroups? And are you using web middlewaregroup for this post route?

Comment: I can't completely say no, but i never touch about middleware , but let me try to add that line

Comment: showing this error "Session store not set on request."

Comment: So weird, Have you this line `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` in your web middlewareGroups?

Comment: there is no any lines like that , so i need to add that line?

Comment: so my problem is the session is not working?

Comment: Yes for sure. Your Kernel.php file must be like this. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php

Comment: the error solved but still not fixed the validation

Comment: Try getting `dd(session()->all())` in blade again.

Comment: array:1 [▼
  "_token" => "fsO0pDSWBIk2RCHIJ00FgR0asTQfjiB8xTBrVwdx"
]

Comment: Hello @shinichirouikebe, your code is fine, no error here, but it will throw `[]` on get request, and it will only throw the error after you click on submit (if session has error)

Comment: @sta may i know what version of laravel you are using? maybe this is laravel 8 issue

Comment: No, I checked on my machine with 8. Its working fine here

Comment: @sta can i see your route?

Comment: @shinichirouikebe `Route::get('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\TestController@test2');`
 and the post route
`Route::post('test', 'App\Http\Controllers\TestController@test2post')->name('test2post');`

Comment: the flow is sending data from form with post method -> send to controller ->if there is a missmatch with the validation rule then feeding back the error to view. that is right?

Comment: i think the validation is work when i submit the form when it null the code bellow the validate is not executed,  the problem is the error message wont show up

Answer (score 0):

As [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) says, you should use one of `@error` directive or loop over `$errors`

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

OR

```
@error('title')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Comment: your 1st way is working in my application but i am trying to show message via your second way but its not working.
NOTE: with your first way errors message is showing.

Comment: Hi @fahdshaykh and thank you for your comment. The second example is directly from [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#the-at-error-directive)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put this code where you want to show error message. Laravel provide this error code.

> In your view page you put this.

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

> In your controller You simply declare which field required.

```
$request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'icons' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Comment: already doing all thing writed at the documentation but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**controller**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


     $validatedData = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'icons' => 'required',
    ])->validate();

    $name = $validatedData['name'];
    $icons = $validatedData['icons'];
```

**blade file** put this above your form

```
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: what happens when you submit an empty form?

Comment: the page refreshed

Answer (score 0):

```
Your validation method is proper after submit button click then check your 
{"name":["The name field is required."],"icons":["The icons field is required."]} this get validation error message <li>{{ $error }}</li>
now you can set now you can set your validation message proper like this 

<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        @if($errors->has('name'))
            <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p>
        @endif

 <input type="file" name="icons" id="icons" class="">
        @if($errors->has('icons'))
            <p class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('icons') }}</p>
        @endif
```

this error message get proper check this format.